# Why are my dictionary datetime values writing into the csv file differently than how they print?

Tags: python-3.x

As my title states, I am trying to take the values from my dictionaries and write them into a `.csv` file. They are datetime files stored in ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`. However, in the file, after the first 5 or so lines they go from `YYYY-MM-DD` format to `MM/DD/YYYY` format. For reference, this data in which these dictionaries gathered from have inconsistent forms (but that is handled). When I simply print the values they all print in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Here is a generic version of my code:

```
file = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')
    for key in date_dict :
        print(date_dict[key])
        file.write('{}\n'.format(date_dict[key])
```

How do I fix this so it is all in `YYYY-MM-DD` format?

Comment: Use `date_dict[key].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: @Vishnudev Thank you. When I implement this though, I get ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'```. I have double checked the ```type``` of all of the values and they are definitely datetime.dates. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Some of them are definitely not `datetime` objects. Check your data. @smallvt

Comment: @Vishnudev you're correct, I see my silly mistake. There was no data for one of the years for one of my date lists, so I set the dict value to 'No data'. Thanks for helping me!!